# PHP page comes up blank on this Mamp setup

Tags: macos, mac, php

I installed MAMP on this Mac OSX 10.6.6.  A phpinfo test seems to say that PHP is installed.  But when I open a file (e.g. index.php) in the browser, it comes up blank.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check file permissions on the PHP files? If the owner of the files does not have permission to execute PHP result could end up blanc.

Answer (score 1):

The phpinfo() command will show you where the error log is located.  This should provide some clues.

Comment: Mamp did not create a php log.  I added error reporting to one of the php files and it still did not create a log.